# search box -> I need to concat first name and last name from one table and join it to a 2nd and return item from 2nd table

Tags: mysql

So the search would be like 'Ozzie Smith'

First table has (username, fname, lname) = osmith, ozzie, smith

Second table has (username, team) = osmith, cardinals

I need to concat the first and last name columns from the first table join it by username on the second table and return the team name.

I have been trying and trying...brain melted. I need your help!

Thanks!

Comment: You can use Soundex matching of names: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's MySQL, you need to use `CONCAT`, not the `+` sign. I also added a `LOWER()` function to avoid capital letter mismatch problem :

```
select team
from table1
join table2 on table2.username = table1.username
where lower(concat(fname,' ',lname)) like lower('%Ozzie Smith%')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably doing something like

```
WHERE fname LIKE '%Ozzie Smith%'
```

which will not work. `fname` will contain only `Ozzie`, and will never match against `Ozzie Smith`. It would also not match if the user enters `Smith, Ozzie`, or any other dual-name variant. You'll have to preprocess the search terms and do something like

```
WHERE (fname LIKE '%Ozzie%') or (fname LIKE '%Smith%')
   OR (lname LIKE '%ozzie%') or (lname LIKE %Smith%')
```

This will get VERY painful as the number of search terms and fields being search goes up. You'd be better off using a FULLTEXT index, where it'll be a simple matter of

```
WHERE MATCH(fname, lname) AGAINST ('Ozzie Smith')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't this work?

```
select
  lname + ', ' + fname as playerName
  , team as teamName
from table1
join table2 on table2.username = table1.username
```

**Update**:

```
where (fname + ' ' + lname) like '%Ozzie Smith%'
```

Comment: I need that all to respond to a where playerName LIKE '%Ozzie Smith%' and I can't figure it out.